# ngrok and https tunnel for asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, https, ngrok

The ASP.NET CORE application, when launched from visual studio, has the address https://localhost:44313/.
To test the performance you need to make a tunnel. I use ngrok and the command:

**ngrok http -host-header=localhost 44313**

But this does not work for https.

Can anyone share a working example?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. Download the current version of ngrok
2. Register and get a token: https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth
3. Run ngrok and set the token with the command: **ngrok authtoken YOUR_AUTHTOKEN**
4. Create a tunnel:
   **ngrok http --host-header=localhost https://localhost:44313**

**Update 11 april 2019**

Comment: I still can't do over https, is there a chance you did other alterations?

Comment: @thalacker All as written above. But I use the latest current version.

Comment: @thalacker forgot to clarify, be sure to use the token obtained during authorization (https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth)

Comment: -host-header should be --host-header

Answer (score 13):

Using ngrok version 2.3.29 and added authtoken (not sure if authtoken influences outcome, I've just added it following the online installation guide).

This command worked for me:

```
ngrok http https://localhost:{your-app-port} -host-header=localhost:{your-app-port}
```

Difference from existing answer: I pass localhost:port to -host-header

Difference form your question: I use `ngrok http https://localhos:port` instead of `ngrok http http://localhos:port` (http**s** instead of http)

Comment: with version 3 you have to use --host-header

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks! I don't think I understand why though. Previously I was forwarding to the http endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

Now you have to put a -- before the host header

```
ngrok http https://localhost:{your-app-port} --host-header=localhost:"your-app-port"
```

Answer (score 4):

Update as March 2023.

After failing to get it running using all options above. I found the following from their documentation : https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/tunnels/http-tunnels/#host-header

To tunnel http

e.g

`ngrok http --host-header=rewrite http://localhost:44345`

if using https,
e.g

`ngrok http --host-header=rewrite --scheme=https https://localhost:44345`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ngrok Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidProthero.NgrokExtensions) in visual studio. The tunneling process is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

If u need to run multiple tunnels on a free-plan u can modify config as

```
version: "2"
authtoken: 2OS8VCciyOWXR7XM33rh6RY79jT_7u8VsgzzfwoewzGnfG3lV
tunnels:
  first:
    addr: 5173
    proto: http    
  second:
    proto: http
    addr: https://localhost:7125
    host_header: rewrite
    schemes: [https]
```

and then run

```
ngrok start --all
```

to find config run

```
ngrok config check
```