# How to access ASP.NET server by IP address using https on private network

Tags: asp.net

How can I access an instance of an ASP.NET server using **https** over a private network?

For example, https://192.168.0.1:5001

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

[ngrok and https tunnel for asp.net core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54800512/ngrok-and-https-tunnel-for-asp-net-core-application)